# Formating date fields in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, date-format

Im working with some date fields like the one i show in the next table:

| Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-07-06T23:00:00 | 2021-07-11T22:59:00 |

My expected output is:

| Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-07-06 | 2021-07-11 |

I use some regex_replace but didnt work

Comment: What's the type of `start_date` and `end_date` ?  If it's `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, you can simply cast it  to `DATE` by using `DATE(start_date)` and `DATE(end_date)`.

Answer (score 0):

As @jaytiger mentioned you can use CAST function from bigquery.

You can refer to [official documentation for CAST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_functions)

Sample example here:

```
SELECT 
CAST(event_datetime AS DATE) AS event_date
FROM sample_table
```

If you are converting from string column you can look at  here [string conversion functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements#format_string_as_day)